# Elementary theory of the double category of spans

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, foundations

Is there an existing axiomization of an "Elementary theory of the double category of spans?"

Among other nice things a category could be then defined as a monad inside the theory of spans.

I think I want something like the [Elementary theory of the category of Sets](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fully+formal+ETCS) or [Elementary theory of the category of categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCC).

I've heard vague references to an [Elementary theory of the category of relations](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCR) which should be similar although personally I would prefer a more double category like presentation. I guess much of the difference is spans are a little more "constructive" than relations?

As I understand things many of the same things you can do with Span you can do with Prof (the category of profunctors) so axiomizations of the category of profunctors ought to be useful as well.

I'm not sure where to start with searching for axiomizations of Span or related categories like Rel and Prof.

Comment: Double categories are internal categories in Cat, so what properties of the double category of spans are particular to them (among double categories) that would allow a more efficient axiomatization compared to the axiomatization of the double category of spans that one would get from e.g. "elementary theory of category of categories"? I'm not familiar with the double category of spans, other than having seen it used as an example of double category, so I honestly don't know the answer to that question.

Comment: @hasManyStupidQuestions TBQH I am exploring and not sure Span is better than formalizing Cat. The approach you describe is more similar to VETT (Virtual Equipment Type Theory). I only have a hunch Span might be better. However, total spans are multi-valued functions and unique spans are partial functions. So relevance logic and affine logic correspond to useful simplifications of Span. This gives me a hunch Span might be more elegant.

Comment: "total spans are multi-valued functions and unique spans are partial functions" - these sound like interesting results. I am not very familiar with the topic so I don't know of references to find explanations -- could you provide any? The closest I found was example 2.34 in this PhD thesis https://www.ioc.ee/~pawel/theses/zanasi.pdf but it doesn't really seem like the same result and the required background seems extensive. The results might answer a question I had https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/165495/is-three-value-logic-related-to-the-categories-of-pointed-sets-or-of-partial-fun

Comment: @hasManyStupidQuestions it's just anafunctors but decategorified https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/anafunction .  Normally you can do everything with relations. Using spans just has nitpicky foundational advantages useful for working on the computer with proof assistants. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/functional+relation